# Auth exception in basic example with angular 2 and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I just follow this example ( [install and setup angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md) ) that is part of the oficial documentation of angularfire2

And as I run this example I have the following error.

[image]

As you can see I have two errors , the first one I  guess is related some how with the autorization , and the following I guess is related with some operation that does not finish well.

The code is exactly as the example. 
And the rules of the data base are this ones :

[image]

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase } from 'angularfire2';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent,[
  FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
  defaultFirebase({ //this data is replace with false data
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "localhost",
    databaseURL: "https://databaseUrl/",
    storageBucket: "gs://storageBucket",
  })
]);
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  heroes : FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.heroes = af.database.list('SuperHeroes');
 }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<h1>
{{title}}
</h1>

<ul *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async">
  <li class="text">
  {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any idea about the problem ?

Comment: set a jsFiddle or something so we can see your current solution

Comment: There is no reason to include images, the `app.component` and `main.ts` would be enough. And your `jsfidle` is broken.

Comment: @JS_astronauts fixed , and I don't understand why you give me a negative vote , since when for given extra info you get that ? And for the link of jsfindle sorry it was the first time that I used .

Comment: I have the same setup and the security rules prevent the app from running. if you set them to `read = true` then it should be fine. Otherwise, You need to implement authentification in your app, to prevent someone from reading data.

Comment: @JS_astronauts I change that , and I continue with the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error when setting: `authDomain: "localhost",`

Make sure you copy it from you firebase profile.
It should look like: `<your.app.name>.firebaseapp.com"`

Comment: Yes , that was the error , thanks. But the error of the "Error: The operation has timed out." it is normal ? I guess is something related with the async from firebase but I come from java and all this new web staff is new for my .

Comment: I remember having that error, I don't know how it disappeared, my version  is `  "angularfire2": "2.0.0-beta.2", "firebase": "^3.0.5",` also `af` depends on RC2...